# between getdate() and DATEADD(m, -1, getdate())) on where clause

Tags: sql

Why `"where  SomeDate between  getdate() and   DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))" -`  not working?
(I try calculate some value over last month)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use other way

```
where  SomeDate between   DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()) and getdate()
```

Answer (score 2):

Because when you use `between` the *lower* value needs to go first.  So, you want:

```
where SomeDate between DATEADD(month, -1, getdate()) and getdate()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use it like this instead:

```
WHERE SomeDate BETWEEN DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE() and GETDATE()
```

The smaller value goes first, which in this case is `DATEADD`

Answer (score 0):

Here some example

```
DECLARE @ServerDate DATETIME = GETDATE()
```

and I add Distinct to avoid redundant data fields

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM FooTable
WHERE SomeDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DD, 0, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, @ServerDate)) AND DATEADD(DD, 1, @ServerDate)
```

DATEADD(DD, 0, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, @ServerDate)) is equivalent to YYYY-mm-dd 00:00:00.000